# Is there a good practice on how to fetch data from DB to Objects or Models

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm setting up a log and I'm trying to create a function to later call with HangFire. The function I want to create will do the following:

Query Select latest Row on Timestamp and get all the column values and reference them to my LogEntires Models attributes.

Is there a good practice to do this in ADO.NET?
How do I handle the return types when returning a select Query?

```
public LogEntries GetEntires(LogEntries entries)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();

        var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 1 *" +
                                          "FROM logTable" +
                                            "ORDER BY LOG_WRITING_TIME desc", conn);
        var dataSet = new DataSet();
        adapter.FillSchema(dataSet, SchemaType.Source, "RadarMF30_log");
        adapter.Fill(dataSet, "logTable");

        DataTable tbl;
        tbl = dataSet.Tables["logTable"];
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var item in tbl.Rows)
        {
            entries.ErrorCode = tbl.Columns[i].ToString(); // ErrorCode must become dynamic. 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Learn how to use an ORM like Dapper. Your problem will be resolved at the query level.

Comment: @Steve I'll look into it for future reference, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good practice is subjective, but as the comment above suggested you are better off using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) vs. writing all that boilerplate ADO.NET code.

I'm guessing ErrorCode is supposed to be a list.

**example (not tested)**

```
    public class LogEntries
    {
        public List<string> ErrorCodes { get; set; }
    }

    public LogEntries GetEntries()
    {
        var logEntries = new LogEntries();
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var errorCodes = conn.Query<string>("YOUR SQL", commandType: CommandType.Text);
            logEntries.ErrorCodes = errorCodes.ToList();
        }

        return logEntries;
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert errorCodes to an object. Since I would like to pass the values/data into other Functions.

Comment: No need as you can pass either LogEntries or errorCodes into other methods.